# Computational complexity of sizes and number of orbits of a group acting on a set

Tags: computational-complexity, group-actions

Given a group action of a group $G$ on a set $X$, is there any way to relate the number of orbits, i.e. $|X/G|=|\{\{g\cdot x:g\in G\}:x\in X\}|$, to the sizes of the orbits, i.e. $|\{g\cdot x:g\in G\}|$ for $x\in X$?

I'm in particular interested in the relation between the computational complexity of these two questions. To be more precise, for a fixed group action, if I know that it's $\#P$-Complete to find the size of an orbit (given an element in $X$), can I then make any statement of the computational complexity of counting the number of orbits?

*Note: I've now asked the same [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313823/computational-complexity-of-sizes-and-number-of-orbits-of-a-group-acting-on-a-se) on mathoverflow, since after two weeks there was only an related answer here.*

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following question: Given two elements of X, are they in the same orbit under the action of G? This problem is Graph Isomorphism complete.

Comment: Checking whether two elements are in the same orbit is a different question! Furthermore, I'm asking about the computational complexity of finding the number of orbits for a fixed group action, given that it's #P-Complete to compute the size or orbits for this group action. That is, I am not asking about the computational complexity in general for all group actions but only for those which computing the size of orbits is #P-Complete and whether for these, if counting orbits is necessarily #P-Complete.